# How to store Java nio files walk() result into a list of String?

Tags: java, java-8, nio

I am working with Java 8 and I have the below code, which lists directory.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:/MyDir"))) {
    paths.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to store the result to `List<String>` and need to suffix a `\` if it's a directory. How can I do this?

Comment: I assume don't want to filter files if you want directories.

Comment: you want to do what? `isRegularFile` takes only files, but you want directories... you need to clarify what you *actually* want

Comment: Does the System.out::println print out directories or files only?

Comment: Hi all, removed the filter.

Comment: The whole idea is that you process the files as `walk()` traverses. You don't need a list and a subsequent traversal.

Comment: this still makes no sense, could you simply explain what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to display directory, as well as files. If it's directory, i want it to be like `directory/` so that i can identify it as directory.

Comment: @Eugene I want to display directory, as well as files. If it's directory, i want it to be like `directory/` so that i can identify it as directory. I want the result in a `List<String>`

Comment: @EJP the sysout is just for testing. I want `List<String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask isn't that hard :

```
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("c:"))) {
        List<String> list = paths
                .map(path -> Files.isDirectory(path) ? path.toString() + '/' : path.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @bowmore.. :)

Comment: `path.toString() + '/'` can be simplified to `path + "/"`…

Comment: @Holger that's possible, but my way only creates 2 Strings

Comment: `"/"` is a string literal and its associated runtime instance is created once in a JVM for the code’s entire lifetime. Chances are high that this string constant even does already exist with the `Path` implementation or some of the related classes. In either case, that single object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger as a rule, I tend to append single characters as characters and not as single character Strings. The motivation being, not creating more Strings than necessary. Your simplification is shorter, but implicit, rather than explicit. I'd argue it is at least in some sense not simpler. Both work and the impact is miniscule in either case. I guess it's a matter of preference, or what you're used to.

Comment: Indeed. Other developers would prefer not to have `path.toString()` twice in the code, hence, add a local variable to the lambda expression. All a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 stream api you could map all your paths to string and collect all to list like this.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\myDir"))) {
    List<String> pathList = paths.map(p -> {
            if (Files.isDirectory(p)) {
                return "\\" + p.toString();
            }
            return p.toString();
        })
        .peek(System.out::println) // write all results in console for debug
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `/` should be added to the end. +1 for the peek.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
    List<Path> files = Files.walk(path).filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".txt")).map(Path::getFileName).sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(Path file : files) {
        System.out.println("File: " + file);
    }
}
```